# React redux proper updating record and reflecting changes on the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

For learning purpose I made this web app where I'm trying to implement crud operations. All works properly except UPDATE, where MongoDB record is updated but changes on the screen are not reflected till the refresh.
I'm still learning therefore not everything is crystal clear, I'm suspecting a problem in a REDUCER... or in the component mapStateToProp object...

What am I doing wrong here?

routes/api
Item.findByIdAndUpdate for sure update's db correctly, but should it also return anything so the reducer/action could react to it?

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require("../../middleware/auth");

// Item Model
const Item = require("../../models/stories");

// @route   GET api/items
// @desc    Get All Items
// @access  Public
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Item.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(items => res.json(items));
});

// @route   PUT api/items
// @desc    Update An Item
// @access  Private
router.put("/:_id", auth, (req, res) => {

  Item.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params._id,
    req.body,
    { new: false, useFindAndModify: false },
    () => {}
  );
});
module.exports = router;
```

reducers

```
import {
  GET_STORIES,
  ADD_STORY,
  DELETE_STORY,
  STORIES_LOADING,
  UPDATE_STORY
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  stories: [],
  loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_STORIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        stories: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case DELETE_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        stories: state.stories.filter(story => story._id !== action.payload)
      };
    case ADD_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        stories: [action.payload, ...state.stories]
      };
    case UPDATE_STORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        stories: action.payload
      };
    case STORIES_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

actions

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  GET_STORIES,
  ADD_STORY,
  DELETE_STORY,
  UPDATE_STORY,
  STORIES_LOADING
} from "./types";
import { tokenConfig } from "./authActions";
import { returnErrors } from "./errorActions";

export const getStories = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setStoriesLoading());
  axios
    .get("/api/stories")
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_STORIES,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};

export const addStory = story => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/stories", story, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_STORY,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
export const updateStory = story => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .put(`/api/stories/${story.id}`, story, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_STORY,
        payload: story
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};

export const deleteStory = id => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .delete(`/api/stories/${id}`, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: DELETE_STORY,
        payload: id
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};

export const setStoriesLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: STORIES_LOADING
  };
};
```

component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input
} from "reactstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { updateStory } from "../../actions/storyActions";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class UpdateStoryModal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  state = {
    id: this.props.idVal,
    modal: false,
    title: this.props.titleVal,
    body: this.props.bodyVal
  };
  static propTypes = {
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const obj = {
      id: this.props.idVal,
      title: this.state.title,
      body: this.state.body
    };

    this.props.updateStory(obj);
    this.toggle();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            size="sm"
            onClick={this.toggle}
          >
            Edit Story
          </button>
        ) : (
          <h4 className="mb-3 ml-4">Please log in to manage stories</h4>
        )}

        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Edit story</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <Form>
              <FormGroup>
                <Label for="story">Title</Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="title"
                  id="story"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.title}
                />
                <Label for="story">Story</Label>
                <Input
                  type="textarea"
                  name="body"
                  rows="20"
                  value={this.state.body}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-dark"
                  style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}
                  onClick={this.onSubmit}
                >
                  Edit story
                </button>
              </FormGroup>
            </Form>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  story: state.story,
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { updateStory }
)(UpdateStoryModal);
```

Comment: just wrote you an answer, let me know if that's helpful to you friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you want to return the updated item from your MongoDB database so that you have something to work with in your reducer. It looks like you've setup your action-creator to be prepared for that type of logic. So we just need to make a couple updates:

In your express route you would want something like:

```
router.put("/:_id", auth, (req, res) => {
  //this returns a promise
  Item.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params._id,
    req.body,
    { new: false, useFindAndModify: false },
    () => {}
  )
  .then((updatedItem) => {
     res.json(updatedItem) //we capture this via our promise-handler on the action
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     return res.status(400).json({ couldnotupdate: "could not update item"})
  })
});
```

Then we can tap into that updated item using `res.data` in your action-creator promise-handler

```
export const updateStory = story => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .put(`/api/stories/${story.id}`, story, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_STORY,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

Now that you have the updated item as an action-payload, we need to update your reducer:

```
case UPDATE_STORY:
  return {
    ...state,
    stories: state.stories.map((story) => {
        if(story._id == action.payload._id){
           return{
               ...story,
               ...action.payload
           } else {
               return story
           }
       }
    })
  };
```

With that you should be able to take the updated story from your back-end and have it reflected to the front.